# Questão simples demais feita por um "experiente"

Tags: debate, suporte

Hoje me deparei com essa questão: [O que é console.log?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38057/o-que-%C3%A9-console-log)

Achei que fosse um novato totalmente perdido mas quando vejo o usuário que postou, é um usuário com alta pontuação no site, o qual também possui site próprio onde mostra uso "avançado" de JavaScript.

Esse tipo de questão, feita por um profissional que aparenta ser experiente, é proposital?
Qual o intuito disso?

1. Ganhar pontos pela pergunta? Caça medalhas?
2. Encher a base de dados do SO-PT com qualquer coisa mesmo que irrelevante?
3. Um teste?
4. Uma piada?

Obs: Isso não é uma crítica. Gostaria apenas de saber o motivo e entender melhor as normas de uso do site.

Comment: Ele dá o contexto num comentário logo abaixo da pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38057/o-que-%C3%A9-console-log#comment73843_38057

Comment: Eu vi o comentário mas ainda está vago.

Comment: A pergunta é básica? Eu não sabia muito bem disto. Tenho boa reputação e foi a melhor informação que consegui sobre o assunto. Claro, eu não sou *webdev*, não procuro muito por isto mas aprendi coisas valiosas lá na resposta. Inclusive recentemente o Zuul me ajudou em um chat externo em um problema específico usando o console que eu achava não se encaixaria bem como pergunta no site. O que é básico para um não é para outro.

Comment: Curiosamente um debate sobre isto ficou aberto: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1338/podemos-aceitar-perguntas-que-pedem-descri%C3%A7%C3%A3o-que-existe-em-documenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: O sistema gosta disso e reconhece através de [Pergunta Legal](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question) e [Resposta Legal](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer). Os usuários do site ativam o sistema fazendo +1 e -1. Por agora,  o +1 tem a vantagem.

Comment: +1 pela pergunta.

Comment: Valeu bigown! Esse link que postou tem uma relação perfeita com o que coloquei aqui.

Comment: Boa pergunta, embora ache que se alguns termos fossem retirados ela não atrairia "demasiada" contrariedade.

Comment: Fica o registro: estou me desfazendo (via recompensas) dos pontos ganhos com essa pergunta. Outro dia vi outro meta-tópico onde aparece de novo a mesma polêmica. Não preciso desse karma nos meus pontos de reputação.

Comment: Achei que era só eu que fazia isso :|

Answer (score 28, accepted):

É para introduzir conhecimento relevante ao site.

Coincidentemente, eu próprio fiz hoje [uma pergunta da qual já sabia a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38034/215). No meu caso era um pouquinho mais complexa, mas o objetivo era o mesmo - quando alguém precisasse de saber a resposta pra mesma (ou, como [apontado por bfavaretto nos comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2170/quest%C3%A3o-simples-demais-feita-por-um-experiente#comment6887_2170), alguém precisar indicar uma referência para um usuário iniciante) ela fosse encontrada aqui mesmo no SOpt.

Algumas pessoas preferem já dar a resposta junto com a pergunta. Outras preferem dar a chance de outra pessoa responder (quem sabe até melhor do que ela própria o faria). Mas de todo modo, é um comportamento aceitável e desejável.

Exceto, é claro, se for "qualquer coisa mesmo que irrelevante". No beta privado, tivemos uma tendência das pessoas postarem perguntas extremamente simples (com auto-resposta) unicamente para ganhar pontos. Oficialmente, era permitido, mas boa parte da comunidade foi contra esse comportamento. No fim das contas, é a qualidade da pergunta que importa, não se ela foi feita pelo motivo X ou Y ou respondida pela pessoa A ou B.

Nesse caso citado, muito embora a pergunta *pareça* simples, o desconhecimento do `console.log` por parte de muitos desenvolvedores causa muitos transtornos para eles próprios e para os outros (já que vivem usando `alert` ou mesmo `document.write` pra isso). E embora o `log` seja a função mais utilizada, a resposta apresentou outras funções relacionadas e relevantes que muita gente - inclusive eu - desconhecia.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Deixou mais claro.
Entendo que o site quer ter mais conteúdo só não entendo muito bem até que ponto algo é considerado "conteúdo relevante" ou "irrelevante/inaceitável". 
Removi a outra parte do texto da minha questão para não levar muito para o lado da crítica e manter uma discussão mais produtiva. 
Então pelo que entendi é meramente uma questão para "encher linguiça", falando a grosso modo e ao mesmo tempo bem conveniente para caça medalhas. Desculpe ser sincero, mas as vezes parece desrespeitoso para com os que procuram participar com seriedade e se deparam com isso.

Comment: @DanielOmine Oi? É justamente o contrário: fazer uma pergunta só para encher linguiça é o que ocorria no início do site, e isso era desencorajado (o pessoal votava contra, pra fechar, e até enchiam o saco dos moderadores com sinalizações) - a ponto de ser uma estratégia inviável pra "caçar medalhas". Agora, eu concordo com você que dizer se algo é "relevante" ou "irrelevante" cai um pouco na subjetividade... Aliás, é pra isso que existe o Meta, pros usuários poderem discutir, opinar, e definir o que deve ou não ser aceito no site, não só em termos de conteúdo como de comportamento.

Comment: @DanielOmine Quanto a "participar com seriedade", o que tem de "não sério" nisso? Estou vendo um usuário que dispôs seu tempo não só pra ajudar um iniciante com suas dúvidas, mas foi além na tentativa de agregar conteúdo que vai ajudar não só àquele mas a outros iniciantes que têm a mesma dúvida. Se ele vai ganhar ou não "pontos" ou "medalhas" por isso é irrelevante - isso é só um pretexto, não deveria ser o ponto central do site. Já vi gente reclamando de "injustiça" na distribuição de pontos do site, mas promover a qualidade do conteúdo tem precedência sobre o aspecto da gamificação.

Comment: @Daniel, abri a pergunta depois de ver que precisava dela para indicar para um novato, conheço o modelo, sei que não é off-topic, ao revés, útil. Exatamente por ser experiente, abri a pergunta. Claro que vou ganhar pontos, quantas vezes isso vai ser googlado? A resposta do Zuul lá é fenomenal (e do Miguel e do Fernando), aprendi algo novo especialmente com a do @Z, você não?

Comment: +1 pelo *inclusive eu - desconhecia*, porque inclusive eu desconhecia. :)

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer também brasofilo e todos os outros.
O ponto é que sou novato no site, quase 1 ano de uso e realmente fico meio perdido sem entender o que é correto ou não por aqui.
Sobre a sua questão ou outras diversas que são simples demais, acho irrelevante demais pois há vasto conteúdo na web sobre esses assuntos "super básicos", "super simples" ou "super seja lá o que for". O que gostaria de entender é se realmente era ou é permitido esse tipo de postagem aqui no SO. [continua no outro post]

Comment: O mgibsonbr já deixou bem claro e de fato era o que eu imaginava. Para mim não muda o que penso, é meramente um tópico "enche linguiça" hahaha. E também conveniente para ganhar medalhas, estrelinhas, purpurinas, etc. Claro, sem querer ofender quem está no site por reputação, medalhinhas, etc. Somos livres, o site incentiva a caça a medalhas e não há nada errado nisso. 
O que acho meio contraditório é "focar" a busca de medalhas ou "maquiar a busca por reputação" por meio de conteúdo tão.. é.. bom, essa coisa aí... rsrsr [continua]

Comment: Deixando as críticas de lado, agradeço novamente e está tudo certo, agora consigo compreender melhor a política do site.

E sobre o brasofilo que perguntou se eu não aprendi algo novo nas respostas titânicas. Não! hehehe Não porque eu particularmente evito ler tópicos ou respostas exageradamente apocalipticamente titanicamente colossais. E quando eu quiser saber mais a fundo sobre o assunto eu posso ir nas documentações oficiais e ler basicamente o mesmo que copiaram, adaptaram e colaram nas respostas aqui no SO.

Então o SO é para ser tipo um wikipedia ou um google de conhecimento técnico?

Comment: [continua]
Sobre o o objetivo do SO, acho que cabe discutir em outro tópico para não tumultuar. a questão principal aqui, por mim já está esclarecida.

Comment: @DanielOmine Sobre seu questionamento `Então o SO é para ser tipo um wikipedia ou um google de conhecimento técnico?`, sugiro ler esse tópico: [O SOPT se encaixa na categoria de “rede social”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1361/3117). Em resumo, a ideia do site não é ajudar os usuários pontualmente, ou seja, ajudar o AP (autor da pergunta) apenas, e sim de se construir um repositório de perguntas e respostas uteis para todos, inclusive para quem nem sequer tem uma conta no site.

Comment: Tem gente que vem ao site [para pegar um peixe, tem gente que vem para aprender a pescar](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1968/201). Os dois tipos de respostas são válidas, mas o site seria bem pobre se fosse só uma peixaria e não uma armada de pescadores. @DanielOmine

Comment: @DanielOmine Os donos do site têm uma meta ambiciosa: querem que *toda* pergunta sobre programação tenha uma ou mais respostas aqui. Querem que qualquer busca por um problema no Google traga um link para o site no topo da lista. Claro que existem critérios (muitas vezes não tão claros) para definir o que vale e o que não vale, mas a simplicidade da pergunta não é um problema.

Comment: Também sou "contra" fazer trabalho alheio. Vejo muitos que fazem todo o serviço do sujeito ao invés de elaborar um escopo (ensinar a pescar).
E também falando sobre fazer serviço de terceiros, o SO tem algum programa de incentivo financeiro ou mesmo contrata os que participam com frequência?
Os que participam com mais afinco são meramente voluntários? Tudo o que ganham é medalhinhas virtuais?
Enquanto isso os donos enriquecem com trabalho alheio de milhares de caça medalhas. É por isso que o site incentiva buscar medalhas e manter o nível de qualidade de conteúdo. É meramente comercial.

Comment: @DanielOmine Sugiro que leia o post ["Are You a Digital Sharecropper"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/are-you-a-digital-sharecropper/) no blog do Jeff Atwood (um dos criadores do StackOverflow), ele discute essa questão dos "donos enriquecerem com trabalho alheio" (*"sharecropping"* é um tipo de [parceria rural](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parceria_rural) em que o dono da terra permite que outras pessoas trabalhem nela, e em troca ganham uma parte da produção). Sobre as "medalhinhas virtuais", sugiro que leia sobre [gamificação](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Continua...

Comment: "É meramente comercial" Não sei quanto ao "meramente", mas o site é mantido por uma empresa, buscando o lucro sim. Todo aspecto gamificado do site (pontos, medalhas) é voltado a **estimular um comportamento positivo**, e muitas vezes esse comportamento se traduz em beneficiar o próprio site como negócio (ex.: as medalhas ["Anunciador"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer) e cia. "premiam" quem traz visitantes ao site via links externos, i.e. gera *page-views*). Sobre incentivo à participação, não, diretamente não há nada. Somos todos voluntários mesmo, por razões particulares.

Comment: De todo modo, cabe notar que o site traz diversos benefícios à comunidade de programadores em geral. Primeiro pra quem pergunta, pois em geral recebe respostas rápidas e de qualidade. Segundo para quem busca por uma resposta. Terceiro, todo o conteúdo que vem dos usuários é livre, através da licença Creative Commons. Quarto, pra quem pergunta, é um modo de demonstrar seu conhecimento, uma espécie de portfólio virtual. Quinto, há o [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) (principal fonte de renda do site, aliás), gratuito para os usuários que querem procurar emprego (os empregadores pagam).

Comment: Obrigado pelos links. Sobre gamificação conheço muito bem pois sou dono de serviços desse tipo. O meu interesse maior era saber a posição dos donos da empresa. Mas de qualquer forma não muda a minha opinião. Entendo que muitos se dispõem a "trabalhar de graça" pela troca de experiência como recompensa, demonstração de conhecimento. etc. Mas enfim, é algo particular e reconheço que devemos respeitar. 
Cada um deve saber o quanto "doar" para a "comunidade" e estar ciente também de que essa doação vai para a empresa.

Comment: Sendo um pouco chato, desculpe pelo sarcasmo mas, é de praxe usar filosofias baratas para justificar ganhos financeiros e dar esmolas a voluntários para mantê-los felizes.  rsrsrs Mas tanquilo.. De qualquer forma continuarei participando exporadicamente e procurando aprender e compartilhar. 

Acho que quando uma pessoa tem muito conhecimento e sabedoria e morre sem passar para outros o que aprendeu em vida, então essa pessoa viveu em vão. Por isso gosto de compartilhar conhecimento.

Comment: Respeito sua opinião, @Daniel, mas tem mais uma coisa que não foi citada. No meu caso, que participo bastante, responder perguntas é também uma forma de aprendizagem. Mesmo que esteja respondendo sobre algo que já domino, estruturar uma resposta e refletir sobre como explicar algo ajuda a consolidar meus próprios conhecimentos. Isso é algo bem concreto que os voluntários podem ganhar com sua participação.

Comment: Tranquilo e compreendo isso muito bem, achei até desnecessário mencionar isso pois o foco estava mais a respeito do objetivo da empresa mantenedora do SO.

Quanto aos motivos dos usuários é algo pessoal de cada um e obviamente devemos respeitar.

O meu intuito maior nessa questão é entender o que é aceitável ou não no site como conteúdo relevante e de qualidade para evitar receber negativos em postagens futuras. Para mim fica chato postar algo e ficar negativado em público sem eu perceber e ter o meu nome vinculado com algo negativo sem eu perceber ou poder me justificar, entende?

Comment: huahuahu agora que vi que essa questão já está negativada.. É isso que não compreendo e acho bagunçado no SO... chega a ser hilário, frustrante.. sei lá... não dá para entender "vocês".
Mas de boa.. o jeito é não postar nada. hahah dá até medo de postar algo aqui.. Menos mal que o Meta SO é privado..
Isso aqui parece mais uma panelinha do que uma comunidade,  honestamente falando. Por mim já basta.. já mudou o foco, é melhor abrir outro topico para discutir essas outras questões, mas eu não vou fazer isso para tomar negativo dessa "panelinha" de novo.. rsrsrs

Comment: @Daniel, a gente ia até te convidar para a Sala de Chat VIP MasonryJS, mas você quebrou a Primeira Regra da Panelinha que é **não falar sobre a panelinha**.

Comment: @DanielOmine Aqui no Meta somos mesmo bem mais liberais com os votos negativos. Sua pergunta está com +2/-3, mostrando certa controvérsia. De todo modo, ser negativado não é nenhuma "vergonha", eu por exemplo acho que essas [duas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14016885/520779) [respostas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15079060/520779) (no SOen) estão OK e por isso não mexo nem removo, apesar do negativo. P.S. Quanto à "panelinha", todo mundo é bem-vindo a participar do Meta. Se só uns poucos o fazem com regularidade, é por falta de interesse da maioria, nós aqui não temos nada a ver com isso...

Comment: valeu @migsonbr! Agora entendo, faz sentido mesmo. Sempre terá os que participam mais e fica parecendo que há "panelinha".. O que acho meio injusto é , se fosse um usuário com alta reputação no meu lugar postando o mesmo que postei, não teria negativo...

Comment: @brasofilo, caramba cara, perdi a oportunidade da minha vida de estar numa sala de chat vip do so fazendo parte da panelinha vip! ... devo aprender a postar menos bobagem então! que vacilo... deixa eu ir ali pular do 15º andar... rsrsrs
Mas por quê "MasonryJS"? rsrsr

Answer (score 7):

**E se houver oportunismo? Algum problema?**

Desde que a pergunta seja boa e que possa vir a ter excelentes respostas...

O site tem medalhas e reputação mesmo para incentivar boas perguntas e boas respostas (*e quem sabe um dia ser um currículo, acho que já é nos USA*).

E esforçar-se para fazer boas perguntas e para dar boas respostas merece reputação e medalhas, claro. O importante é que o site seja de boa qualidade para quem procura uma resposta a uma dúvida que tenha.

**Porque esperar que um utilizador novato faça essa mesma pergunta(quem sabe uma má pergunta) e não fazer logo a pergunta?**

**Não tem esse mesmo direito um usuário com alta reputação do que um usuário com baixa reputação?**

Eu se acho que essa pergunta vai ser "quente" então faço-a claro, até para ajudar o site a evoluir. Se muita gente pesquisar por Console.log no google acaba chegando aqui o que é ótimo para o site.

A mim as vezes também me acontece de ficar na dúvida de coisas simples que já utilizo a anos. Já aprendi aqui muitas coisas simples que eu achava que percebia e afinal não estava nem perto da resposta.

Claro que se alguém começar ai a ir buscar pergunta atrás de pergunta ao SOen não será bem visto pelo comunidade, mas não vejo mal de um utilizador experiente criar uma pergunta quente, simples, mas com respostas bem complexas.

Comment: Entendido!  Cara, até pensei em zuar, por exemplo, abrir uma pergunta do tipo "O que é PHP e como usar?" ou "O que é HTML e qual usa usabilidade?" heheh.. Então posso sair abrindo qualquer coisa simples assim? Em 1 semana chego no topo de membros mais reputados só com isso.. Então a reputação perde valor pois não tem um critério de "qualidade" real. Pois não considera o nível da questão.
Um membro com 5 mil pontos de reputação, quantos desses pontos provieram de oportunismos? 
Sugiro que os admins pensem num tipo de pontuação menor para questões "oportunas".

Comment: @DanielOmine se criasses essas perguntas eras capaz de ter pontos negativos. Tem de ser uma boa pergunta, e normalmente é um usuário que toda a gente conhece o seu valor e que não está querendo a reputação só por si.

Comment: Entendo e claro que foi meramente exemplos. Mas discordo disso que usuários com maior quantidade de pontos devem ter mais respeito que outros que não tem, pois formam-se panelinhas. Todos tem que ser respeitados por igual. Se não isso aqui fica semelhante a pirâmides de marketing multinível onde quem está no topo sempre ganha dos "bobos" de baixo.
Os do topo deveriam ser os últimos a pensar em criar "tópicos caça medalhas". Se os do topo podem, por que os demais não podem? Os do topo deveriam ser os primeiros a dar exemplo. Do contrário, cria-se um ambiente desigual.

Comment: Não é isso @DanielOmine não tem nada a ver, se fosse um usuário novo a pergunta era aceita e votada da mesma forma porque era uma boa pergunta. Desculpa se me fiz entender mal. Agora se fosse ai umas quantas em serie isso sim seria mal visto.

Comment: Como disseste @DanielOmine e muito bem os com maior reputação tem de ter o mesmo respeito que os de menor reputação. Então tem toda a legitimidade para fazer perguntas fáceis. Não achas?

Comment: `usuários com maior quantidade de pontos devem ter mais respeito que outros` quem afirmou uma coisa dessas??

Comment: Ah fmz !! interpretei pelo o que vc tinha colocado. Mas claro, se for assim em série, poderia ser passível a punição com advertência ou banimento, acho. Mas puxando o assunto, eu posso fazer algo maquiado ?

Comment: Exemplo, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38308/deixar-texto-de-site-gerenci%C3%A1vel

Comment: @DanielOmine se você acha que perguntar coisas simples é caçar reputação, o que acharia de perguntar algo que já sabe e já responder junto com a publicação da pergunta? Veja: [Responder sua própria pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422/3117)

Comment: Mas, por favor, não estou dizendo que o autor desse link esteja maquiando para caçar medalha.. mas pode estar fazendo.. Vai saber né.. 
Então o que eu quero colocar é por exemplo, eu sou um designer, então eu escrevo na questão que sou designer, não entendo nada de programação e pergunto algo bem bobo sobre JAVA, tipo como concatenar X + Y.. só exemplo.. Então ganho meus positivos e fica tudo certo. heheh..
Fazendo nesses esquemas, consigo criar vários em 1 semana ou 1 mês e fica meio dificil  de perceber o flood, sacou?
Na verdade percebi uns que fazem isso de um jeito que parece proposital

Comment: @Math, leia os comentarios que entenderá. Interpretei isso do comentário 2 do Jorge B, o qual já esclareceu na sequência. Isso já está resolvido, blz?

Comment: @DanielOmine se as perguntas realmente fossem boas e que ajudassem o site a evoluir, não estou a ver o mal disso.

Comment: @Math, sobre responder a própria questão!! hahha isso é muito loco.. Aí sim, nmais um meio de maquiar a caça por medalhas também.. Mas veja bem, deixo claro novamente que não estou demonizando quem caça medalha ou que todos esses exemplos sejam oportunistas. Creio que a maioria seja idônea e legímita

Comment: @Jorge B. Outros já explicaram isso e não é isso que estou colocando em jogo. A questão é se é válida, relevante ou oportunista.

Comment: @DanielOmine o site tem medalhas e reputação mesmo para incentivar boas perguntas e boas respostas (e quem sabe um dia ser um currículo, acho que já é nos USA). E esforçar-se para fazer boas perguntas e para dar boas respostas merece reputação e medalhas, claro. O importante é que o site seja de boa qualidade para quem procura uma resposta a uma dúvida que tenha.

Comment: @Math, "se você acha que perguntar coisas simples é caçar reputação," -> Não coloquei a questão dessa forma leviana.. O contexto e os argumentos estão todos acima.. Não preciso explicar tudo de novo.

Comment: @Jorge B. Isso eu entendo.. e já explicaram também aqui umas 3 ou 4 vezes. Mas eu já compreendia, obviamente. (sobre incentivo a caça medalhas, curriculo, etc)

Comment: @DanielOmine ok ok, não precisa se explicar, vou procurar onde conversam sobre isso. É que "acima" é relativo, pois eu por exemplo ordeno as respostas do Meta por "Ativo" logo provavelmente quer dizer que são comentários das outras respostas dessa mesma pergunta, que para mim aparecem abaixo, mas isso já é outra coisa. É que achei que tinha concluído isso a partir da resposta ou comentários dessa resposta do JorgeB.

Comment: O propósito do site é conseguir ter um grande repositório de informações sobre desenvolvimento de software. Este é o único objetivo do site. A gamificação, que foi feita por quem entende do assunto foi criada e melhorada de forma comunitária para auxiliar nisto. Ninguém está muito preocupado com o uso do site para ganhar reputação ou medalha se estiver cumprindo o objetivo do site. A comunidade regula isto. Essencialmente as pessoas ganham o que merecem. Pode não ter a maior justiça do mundo mas a vida não é justa, nenhum jogo é totalmente justo, definir o que é justo é muito difícil.

Comment: Aqui existe gamificação e não idealização ou "perficcionização" da vida. Embora sempre um ou outro que acha que isto é algo alcançável. Claramente você não entendeu ainda o que é uma pergunta boa ou não para o site. Os exemplos citados de algo ruim, são considerados bons e os exemplos que deu do que você poderia fazer para ganhar reputação com pergunta boa e fácil, provavelmente seriam fechados porque para responder não seria... fácil o suficiente (o motivo concreto é claro que seria outro, não existe fechamento por ser muito fácil ou difícil.

Comment: Toda essa discussão não está levando a lugar algum. Sugiro você fazer propostas **concretas** de como o site pode melhorar e resolver os problemas que você acha que existem. Os fundadores também já demonstraram que não se importam se alguém fizer um site semelhante resolvendo os problema deste. EU adoraria usar um site que funcione melhor que este. Talvez queira se inscrever e aprender mais sobre o assunto: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61762/gamification

Comment: E, como nota final, @Daniel, minha reputação em vários sites é por responder centenas e centenas de perguntas, medalhas por editar e ajudar na moderação e suporte outras tantas centenas de centenas. Não vou fazer pergunta fácil sem saber exatamente o que estou fazendo.

Comment: Entendo @brasofilo. E creio mesmo que vcs do top não são uns meros "caça medalhas". Sempre vejo vcs postando e fazendo moderações. Se tem alta pontuação é por mérito legítimo.