# Como perguntar algo que você já sabe a resposta, com intuito de agregar conhecimento ao site?

Tags: debate

As vezes, eu **faço perguntas que eu já conheço a resposta**¹, que ao meu ver seriam **úteis** e **agregariam conhecimento** ao site, ou então eu conheço apenas uma solução/resposta e **gostaria de conhecer outros meios/métodos**.

Porém, **quem está do outro lado não sabe disso** e talvez a minha pergunta possa **não demonstrar nenhum esforço de pesquisa** e como podemos ver [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote):

> O voto a favor em uma pergunta ou resposta sinaliza para o restante da comunidade que uma publicação é interessante, com boa pesquisa e útil, enquanto o voto contra uma publicação sinaliza o oposto: que a publicação contém informações erradas, **tem pouco trabalho de pesquisa** ou não comunica a informação.

Também podemos encontrar no texto indicativo do botão downvote:

[image: downvote]

Logo, podemos perceber que uma pergunta deste patamar poderá sofrer um voto-contra(downvote) que na verdade, seria "injusto".

### Qual seria o real motivo desta pergunta?

Saber como elaborar uma pergunta deste tipo, para que outros olhos vejam-na como uma pergunta positiva, que colabora para o site, e não como uma pergunta que demonstra indisposição do autor em pesquisar acerca antes de perguntar.

Saber elaborar uma pergunta deste tipo também pode evitar pensamentos como [**este**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2170/3082) em que o usuário pensa que o autor da pergunta está fazendo uma *"caçada por votos"* ou até *"uma piada"*

¹: Algumas perguntas que fiz já conhecendo a resposta:

- [Como dividir uma imagem em várias partes com link?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41080/3082)
- [Como obter apenas os números de uma string em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3719/3082)
- [Como redirecionar o usuário para outra página em JavaScript/jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3312/3082)

Comment: Acho que nesses casos a única prevenção contra votos negativos é fazer com que a pergunta cumpra os 3 requisitos: pesquisa, utilidade e claridade. Ainda assim, nada impede que alguém por *qualquer motivo*, justo ou injusto, faça um -1.

Comment: É. Acho que não importa muito se você já sabe a resposta ou não, não é isso que define a qualidade da pergunta. Uma estratégia possível para evitar que achem "uma piada" é deixar para postar sua própria resposta mais tarde. Outra é não se importar com esse tipo de opinião, nem com os votos contra.

Comment: Concordo integralmente com a resposta do @utluiz. Se você sabe a resposta, inclua-a na pergunta deixando claro que está buscando por alternativas e porque. Mas honestamente se você não tem dúvida, acho que não tem muito valor (para a comunidade) fazer a pergunta.

Comment: @PauloRoberto, que valor? Pergunto isso honestamente porque acho que mais vale que uma pessoa que genuinamente não sabe e está buscando conhecimento se cadastre no site e faça a pergunta do que ela encontre a resposta em uma pesquisa e nunca se interesse em participar da comunidade. Não acho que esse tipo de crescimento "artificial" seja positivo no longo prazo. Ter um número grande de perguntas não é o mesmo de ter uma grande e participativa comunidade. Também não acho que usar expressão como "é indiscutível" aqui seja algo positivo.

Comment: Quanto mais conhecimento agregado aqui ao site, mais valor ele terá, seu argumento do usuário é falho pois como que um usuário vai saber que o pt.stackoverflow.com existe se ele não encontrar nada referente a sua pesquisa no google, nunca vai saber. Agora se existir uma pergunta bem feitinha e uma resposta bem explicada ele vai tanto achar o site quanto adorar o site por ter resolvido a dúvida dele e talvez possa se sentir no dever de pelo menos efetuar um cadastro pra votar positivamente a resposta e a pergunta posteriormente, ou então se ele tiver uma duvida adicional, comentar acerca disto.

Comment: @PauloRoberto, dizer que meu ponto está "errado" porque você não concorda comigo é justamente o tipo de coisa que vai contra seu objetivo de ver uma comunidade grande e participativa. Eu não acho que o SO _dependa_ do google, a esta altura. Este é o tipo de prática que não vejo acontecer em outros sites (mas posso estar errado) - o que pode indicar que realmente não é uma boa ideia. Mais vale incentivar quem não conhece/participa a entrar no site, na minha opinião.

Comment: Desculpe, "errado" não - "falho".

Comment: Pelo visto você se equivocou ao achar que me equivoquei. Eu disse **"falho"** pois não é errado, pois é sua opinião tenho que respeita-la, porém a argumentação que apresentaste **falhou** em me convencer pelo fato de que não é necessário deixar perguntas "em aberto" para que usuários novos possam "participar" do site, pois participar do site não é apenas perguntar algo, e sim responder perguntas, comentar, votar na qualidade das perguntas/respostas, sinalizar, editar, analisar, reabrir, fechar, proteger, dentre muitas outras formas de participação. **Obs: SOpt não é tão conhecido quanto o SO**

Comment: Sim, @PauloRoberto, me equivoquei e corrigi logo em seguida (fiz questão de não editar para que você pudesse usar isso contra mim se quisesse - até pra entender qual é sua intenção aqui). Fica assim então. Você não me convenceu que encher o site de perguntas que ninguém perguntou tem valor para a comunidade e eu não te convenci que isso é, a longo prazo ruim para a o site que pode acabar sendo uma biblioteca vazia. Não vou ser arrogante de dizer que seu argumento é "falho" - só não concordo com ele. Até mesmo porque não há evidência de que ele funcione.

Comment: Veja, @PauloRoberto, não sou seu inimigo. Adoraria que o SOpt fosse uma comunidade gigante e talvez parecida com o SO de que eu gosto tanto. Como você parece estar bastante disposto a investir tempo na comunidade, me parece que, por exemplo, monitorar as perguntas sem resposta e responder, ou mesmo fazer qualquer uma das outras coisas que você citou sejam modos *muito* mais produtivos de ajudar.

Comment: Bem, Esta discussão não está levando nós a lugar nenhum, e também já está longa demais e não está sendo positiva para esta pergunta, sugiro que nós devemos deletar nossos comentários.

Comment: Paulo, acho que sempre se pode aprender alguma coisa, nem que seja sobre quem está opinando ;) - Minha argumentação inicial segue na linha da do @utluiz então não vejo razão de inclui-la como uma resposta. Acho que nossos comentários aqui podem ser interessante para as pessoas no futuro, você pode não concordar com meu ponto de vista mas talvez alguém mais possa. No meta, sempre é positiva a diversidade de ideias.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Não vejo uma forma absolutamente correta de perguntar algo que já se sabe. Sempre há a chance de alguém achar que faltou de esforço. Se você responder a si mesmo, alguém pode achar que você só está querendo ganhar votos ou fazer algum tipo de autopromoção.

Entretanto, para amenizar isso, você poderia incluir em sua pergunta a abordagem que você conhece, questionando então sobre possíveis desvantagens e problemas ocultas, além de formas alternativas e mais eficientes de obter o resultado.

Nesse cenário, as chances de respostas ruins diminuem, pois quem não entende muito do assunto não vai saber fazer melhor. Da mesma forma, as chances de boas respostas aumentam, porque vai forçar usuários mais esforçados a pensar realmente sobre o problema.

Answer (score 6):

Na minha opinião, e como próprio disseste esse tipo de perguntas podem se dividir em 2 tópicos diferentes:

1. faço perguntas que eu já conheço a resposta, que ao meu ver seriam
   úteis e agregariam conhecimento ao site
2. conheço apenas uma solução/resposta e gostaria de conhecer outros
   meios/métodos.

**Para o primeiro caso**, a minha opinião pode ser um pouco forte, mas a verdade é que vejo completamente como desnecessária ou até melhor não havia de acontecer.

*Justificação*:
Mais uma vez digo, na minha opinião, normalmente essas perguntas são de um nível de dificuldade baixo, são perguntas que seriam perguntadas por novos utilizadores, um pouco inexperientes na programação/linguagem em questão, e para mim o site não pode viver pela comunidade que está neste momento, mas sim pela comunidade que vai chegando, isto é novos utilizadores/Programadores que tem duvidas, se essas duvidas já estão todas no site, tiram um pouco o funcionamento do site, isto é novos utilizadores não fazem perguntas, logo não recebem pontuação, para não falar relativamente a respostas que acontece o mesmo, se essas perguntas já foram respondidas mais uma vez esses novos utilizadores não tem forma de responder a perguntas mais simples que por vezes aparecem de outros novos utilizadores.

*Contra*

o contra desta minha opinião é a visualização que o site tem no "mundo da Internet" é verdade que quanto mais conteúdo mais visualizações, mas isso pelo que me tenho apercebido penso que não seja o problema porque o site está num bom crescimento(pelo menos até agora). 
Uma frase curiosa:

> *"Nove pessoas não fazem um bebê em 1 mês"* <sup><sub>Fred Brooks</sub></sup>

*Exceção:*

Como tudo tem a sua exceção, que é por exemplo no caso de querer dar uma resposta a uma pergunta que precisava de um assunto que poderia estar em outra resposta, nesse caso concordo, acho que seria de bem, no mesmo tempo que adiciona a pergunta adicionar a resposta e não sei mas dava como sugestão marcar como "Wiki da Comunidade" assim a resposta poderia ser melhorada por todos os que tem esse direito.

<sup>(obs: nao sei "Wiki da Comunidade" pode ser usada para este caso)</sup>

**Para o segundo caso** concordo perfeitamente, desde simplesmente não espete a pergunta, deve dizer qual a maneira que sabe fazer, por vezes fazemos 10 linhas de código quando podíamos usar só 1, e até que alguém nos diga alguma coisa vamos pensar sempre que as 10 linhas são a melhor maneira.

*Contra*

Não sei até que ponto não vai gerar umas resposta na base da opinião e gostos, acho que se tem que ter a noção da pergunta

Comment: No exemplo que dá, me parece um uso legitimo do WdaC.